# How to Show that $S=\{(x,y)\in R^2:x>y^2\}$ is open

Tags: general-topology

Show that $S=\{(x,y)\in R^2:x>y^2\}$ is open

quite simple one. We need to choose $\epsilon$ for open balls: $D((x_0,y_o),\epsilon)\subset S$ ,$\forall x_o,y_o\in S$.

we can take $\epsilon$ as the closest distance to the parabola. but couldnt do

Comment: Can you just use facts about continuous functions?  Or do you have to use the epsilon definition?

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar No, that's not a proof by contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to take $\epsilon$ as the *closest* distance to the parabola.

Take $(x,y) \in S$.  We have $x > y^2 \implies x - y^2 > 0$.

If $0 < r < 1$, note that
$$
(x-r) - (y+r)^2 = (x - y^2) - (r - 2yr + r^2) > (x - y^2) - (2 + 2|y|)r
$$
So, select and $r>0$ satisfying $r < \min\{(x - y^2)/(2 + 2|y|),1\}$.  How can we show that the ball of radius $r$ about $(x,y)$ is contained in $S$?

Answer (score 2):

As we know $f(x,y)=x-y^2$ is a function that is continuous on  $\mathbb R^2$ and we also know that  $[0,\infty]$ is a open set in $\mathbb R$.  Hence. $f^{-1}([0,\infty])=S=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:x>y^2\}$ is a open set in $\mathbb R^2$..... q.e.d.

Answer (score -1):

Property: A set is open if its complement is closed. Every open ball of radius d around any point of x<=y² intersects infinite points of x<=y² so the complement of S is closed and S is open.